# How do objc_autoreleaseReturnValue and objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I read a book named "Pro multithreading and memory management for iOS and OS X”,it has the content of the Thread Local Storage. The general meaning is that if there is a retain operation outside for the class method’s return value:
Autorelease is not called within objc_autoreleaseReturnValue inside the class method.
Retain is not called within objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue outside the class method.
So that the object will not be push into autoreleasePool,the object will be kept by Thread Local Storage.
I written the code same as the book,but I found this object in the autoreleasePool, so I want ask what is going on?

[image: enter image description]

[image]

Comment: http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/

Answer (score 0):

Testing under Xcode 9 -- on the simulator and on macOS itself, it doesn't seem like the magic autoreleaseReturnValue/retainAutoreleaseReturnValue bypasses the pool as expected.

On an actual iOS device, it seems to work as you'd expect.

[image: Screenshot of ARC eliminating autorelease-pool usage]